# Как реализовать подсветку обьекта в Swing?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Доброго времени суток. Есть задание схематически отобразить человеческую фигуру руки ноги голова и тд. Все это хочу отобразить схематически в виде прямоугольников (возможно с соответствующими изображениями). Каждый прямоугольник должен активироваться по нажатию определенной кнопки 1,2,3 и тд. После активации нужно его както выделить или подсветить. Подскажите как  лучше реализовать это выделение и какие элементы SWING для отображения частей тела использовать? Спасибо!

Comment: Реализовал с помощью обычных jbutton. При перемещении табом между элементами подсвечивает название кнопки.